# ¿Como soluciono que netbeans no termina de compilar ningun programa, se queda en "running" y jamas termina?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-11.3

[image: No avanza de ahí y esto sucede hasta en un hola mundo, solo permanece en "running"]

Ya estuve buscando soluciones pero no funciona nada.

Comment: Si colocas un punto de interrupción dentro del while si funciona?

Comment: El problema no es el código,  ya corrí ese código en terminal y funciona perfecto, pasa que netbeans no me compila nada, ni si quiera un hola mundo, siempre se queda colgado en "running".

Answer (score 0):

El problema es probablmente por estarle dando en "ejecutar" varias veces y dejarlo ahí corriendo, minimizar el panel y creer que el programa ya terminó. Recomiendo la lectura sobre cómo utilizar netbeans antes de utilizarlo.

El programa no termina porque seguramente está esperando input en stdin con la llamada a `readLine`, que es un *blocking-call*.

Para detener el programa simplemente hay que abrir el panel y escribir no, para que el ciclo termine, o bien darle click en la "x" que aparece a un lado de "Running..."